# How to make qlineedit only for some string?

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I'm newer for qt. I want to make a lineedit only sell signals for some string,like `apple,banana,melon`. How can I get it with regex or other method?

Comment: Maybe `QComboBox` is a better choice?

Comment: @vahancho emm,I know but I want to make QComboBox can input specific string,too.(The actual list is too long to drag to choose,. To use completer I think I must make it editable. Or you know how to make it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `QComboBox` and check it's `editable` flag

[image]